# How to get information about items inside cloudwatch metrics?

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I've created a table in cloudwatch and I would like to insert a new item only if all the same three fields weren't inserted in the last hour.
Here is the current status of my table:
[Current status of the metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cymdT.png)

I've inserted the information using Python and put_metric_data API:

```
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    response = cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
            MetricData=[
                {
                    'MetricName': 'Counter',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'Name',
                            'Value': "Bob"
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'accountId',
                            'Value': "222"
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'Pet',
                            'Value': "Cat"
                        },
                    ],
                    'Unit': 'Count',
                    'Value': 1
                },
            ],
            Namespace='Test_table'
        )
```

Once a new entry arrives, I'm trying to check if it already been inserted in the last 60 minutes time frame using get_metric_data with no success so far:

```
response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
     MetricDataQueries=[
         {
             "Id": "my_id",
             "MetricStat": {
                 "Metric": {
                     "Namespace": "Test_table",
                     "MetricName": "Counter",
                     "Dimensions": [
                         {
                             "Name": "Name",
                             "Value": "first_name"
                         },
                         {
                             "Name": "accountId",
                             "Value": "Bank_id"
                         },
                         {
                             "Name": "Pet",
                             "Value": "Pet_type"
                         }
                     ]
                 },
                 "Period": 300,
                 "Stat": "Sum",
                 "Unit": "None"
             },
         },
     ],
     StartTime=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24),
     EndTime=datetime.datetime.now(),
 )
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a  more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: This looks like a really bizarre way to use a metrics system.

Comment: I am trying to avoid inserting duplications into the metric. I want the graph to be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a unit mismatch, you're publishing `Count` but requesting `None`.

Comment: I keep getting
 {'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'my_id', 'Label': 'Counter', 'Timestamps': [], 'Values': [], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}], 'Messages': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '0e562441-efd8-44af-841f-c5a2368c4d88', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '0e562441-efd8-44af-841f-c5a2368c4d88', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '493', 'date': 'Tue, 05 May 2020 19:51:56 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Comment: Even with `Count` in the get_metric_data?

Comment: Yes. I keep getting an empty response.